# Send kubernetes container application logs (stdout and stderr) to UDP server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, syslog

I know docker has options like syslog `log-driver` and `log-opts` so that it can be used to send the logs to say, the UDP server.

Marathon is the docker orchestrator here and a config file has the below:

```
    {
      "key": "log-driver",
      "value": "syslog"
    },
    {
      "key": "log-opt",
      "value": "syslog-address=udp://some-udp-server:port"
    },
```

The existing setup is such that certain downstream systems/entities take the information received on this UDP server to create visualisations on Grafana.

How do I achieve the same in a k8s manifest file that I'm deploying via helm3? Or is there a third-party application I need to use? Basically, I want to send the logs that come in the `kubectl logs -f <pod_name>` command to this UDP server with minimal intrusion.  I would only like to replace this part of the flow so that I don't have to disturb any of the downstream systems.

Comment: See [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the Kubernetes documentation: you cannot control the log target on a per-container or per pod basis, but you can set up a collector to read the logs off of disk.  Setting this up is a cluster-administration problem, not the sort of programming question that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you give me some pointers to a log collector application, something that I can install/setup with relevant configuration and emulate this behaviour that I require? I'm new to this problem and don't know what to look for or start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David suggested there is no option to control the log target. However as requested for log collector application writing this answer.

If your **application** is **streaming** the **UDP** logs you can use the **[Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/products/source-available/)** Opensource. It uses **Mongo & Elasticsearch** as backend databases. We been using **Graylog** to collect logs from the application POD.

Now regarding the **log** **collector** for `kubectl logs -f <POD>` you can push all these logs from the **Worker Node** file system using the **fluentd** collector. [Log location](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#log-location-node) will be `/var/log/pods`

You can use the **Fluentd** collector along with the **Graylog** Gelf UDP input

```
Fluentd -> pushing over gelf UDP -> Graylog input saving to Elasticsearch
```

Here is the ref you can follow : https://docs.fluentd.org/how-to-guides/graylog2

Above example uses **Graylog2** now [Graylog3](https://www.graylog.org/products/source-available/) version is available opensource would suggest checking out that.

You can refer my Github repo : https://github.com/harsh4870/OCI-public-logging-uma-agent

Will get more idea about how deployment setting up log file on **Node's filesystem** and further it gets processed by **collector** although not using **fluentd** but just for ref.

Oracle **OCI** **UMA** agent also similar job like **fluentd** collector only, **parsing** & **pushing** logs to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services like use

1-graylog GELF Driver

2-EFK

3- ...

And have an independent (container name & container ID) log for each container

[https://devopscube.com/setup-efk-stack-on-kubernetes/#:~:text=Conclusion-,What%20is%20EFK%20Stack%3F,large%20volumes%20of%20log%20data](https://devopscube.com/setup-efk-stack-on-kubernetes/#:%7E:text=Conclusion-,What%20is%20EFK%20Stack%3F,large%20volumes%20of%20log%20data).

```
.................................................
input:
    tcp:
      service:
        type: ClusterIP
      ports:
        - name: gelfHttp
          port: 12221
.........................................................
```